# filter associative array that has another array inside it

Tags: php, laravel

I have this `$data`, which holds an array of records from schedules table.

If you want to see the code, please check this [repository](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-School-Timetable-Calendar/blob/56f81b3e244276955c2d181a7b2d00dff115960c/app/Services/CalendarService.php#L45) from LaravelDaily, it's the same code I'm working on.

```
"07:00 AM - 07:05 AM" => array:5 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
]
"07:05 AM - 07:10 AM" => array:5 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
]
"07:10 AM - 07:15 AM" => array:5 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
]
"07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => array:5 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "schedule_id" => 10
    "time" => "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM"
    "subject_name" => "Subject Abc"
  ]
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
]
```

I want to only return/show the `array` that has another `array` inside it and remove the others like what you will see below.

In this case it's **07:15 AM - 07:20 AM**

```
"07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => array:5 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "schedule_id" => 10
    "time" => "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM"
    "subject_name" => "Subject Abc"
  ]
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
]
```

Is that possible without using a `foreach` loop?

What I use:

Laravel 9.33

PHP 8.1

Comment: does the inner array always in index 2?

Comment: Maybe `$data = $data['07:15 AM - 07:20 AM'];` ?

Comment: @Lessmore no, it depends on the day of the schedule, 2 means Wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` by a custom callback function.

```php
$list = [
    "07:00 AM - 07:05 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:05 AM - 07:10 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:10 AM - 07:15 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => [
            "schedule_id"  => 10,
            "time"         => "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM",
            "subject_name" => "Subject Abc",
        ],
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ]
];

function myFunc($arr) {
    return array_filter($arr, 'is_array');
}
$filtered = array_filter($list, 'myFunc');
var_dump($filtered);

/**
Output:

Array
(
    [07:15 AM - 07:20 AM] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [schedule_id] => 10
                    [time] => 07:15 AM - 07:20 AM
                    [subject_name] => Subject Abc
                )

            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

)
*/
```

Edited:

By `return array_filter($arr, 'is_array');` as a callback function its can extract the array on any index, not only index 2.

Comment: Filtering seems kind of pointless when you are always checking at index 2 element.

Comment: @Lessmore thank you, the only thing is it's always in index 2, it depends on the day of the schedule, 2 means Wednesday.

Comment: @LuckyPerson I edited the answer based on the day. Now can be dynamic based on any day.

Comment: @Lessmore I got another question if you can help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955640/filter-associative-array-that-contains-static-value

Comment: @Lessmore I have another question, do you have any idea on this type of problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182000/formatting-array-response-from-controller

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already using Laravel, you might want to try this:

```
collect($data)->filter(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->contains(function ($subItem) {
        return is_array($subItem);
    })
});
```