# filter associative array that contains all the same value of 1

Tags: php, laravel

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73954693/20147460) and got a working answer. However I have another question just a bit different from the previous one.

I have this `$data`, which holds an array of records from schedules table.

If you want to see the `code` that generates this array, you can see it from this [file](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-School-Timetable-Calendar/blob/56f81b3e244276955c2d181a7b2d00dff115960c/app/Services/CalendarService.php#L45) from LaravelDaily, it's the same code I'm working on.

The content of `$data` array below contains a schedule with the ids of `9` and `11`.

Schedule Id `9` has the starting time of **07:00 AM** and ending time of **08:00 AM** (Wednesday).

Schedule Id `11` has the starting time of **07:00 AM** (the same with Schedule Id `9` but only differs in the Day (Friday). I didn't include the ending time of this in the array.

```
$data = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1,
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:10 AM - 06:15 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:15 AM - 06:20 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:20 AM - 06:25 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:25 AM - 06:30 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:30 AM - 06:35 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:35 AM - 06:40 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:40 AM - 06:45 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:45 AM - 06:50 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:50 AM - 06:55 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:55 AM - 07:00 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "07:00 AM - 07:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => [
      "schedule_id" => 11,
      "subject_name" => "Subject Abc",
      "rowspan" => 12
    ],
    3 => 1,
    4 => [
      "schedule_id" => 9,
      "subject_name" => "Subject Bac",
      "rowspan" => 24
    ]
  ],
  "07:05 AM - 07:10 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:10 AM - 07:15 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:20 AM - 07:25 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:25 AM - 07:30 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:30 AM - 07:35 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:35 AM - 07:40 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:40 AM - 07:45 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:45 AM - 07:50 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:50 AM - 07:55 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:55 AM - 08:00 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ]
]
```

The previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73954621/filter-associative-array-that-has-another-array-inside-it/73954693), what I want is to filter only the array that has another array inside it.

But now I want to remove array element if all of it's `index` contains only the value of `1`.

Here's what it looks like:

```
// to be removed from the $data array
$data = [
  "06:00 AM - 06:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:05 AM - 06:10 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:10 AM - 06:15 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:15 AM - 06:20 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:20 AM - 06:25 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:25 AM - 06:30 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:30 AM - 06:35 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:35 AM - 06:40 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:40 AM - 06:45 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:45 AM - 06:50 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:50 AM - 06:55 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ],
  "06:55 AM - 07:00 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
  ]
]
```

The final form of the `$data` array is shown below.

```
$data = [
  "07:00 AM - 07:05 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => [
      "schedule_id" => 11,
      "subject_name" => "Subject Abc",
      "rowspan" => 12
    ],
    3 => 1,
    4 => [
      "schedule_id" => 9,
      "subject_name" => "Subject Bac",
      "rowspan" => 24
    ]
  ],
  "07:05 AM - 07:10 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:10 AM - 07:15 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:20 AM - 07:25 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:25 AM - 07:30 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:30 AM - 07:35 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:35 AM - 07:40 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:40 AM - 07:45 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:45 AM - 07:50 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:50 AM - 07:55 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ],
  "07:55 AM - 08:00 AM" => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 0
  ]
]
```

Q: Why I want to remove it?

A: Because I don't want to show it in the schedule `table`, only the time taken from the schedule will be shown.

Q: Why not stick to the answer on your previous question?

A: I realized that I need the other array of time that is doesn't have an array inside it but has the value of `0`, because the `0` is telling that that time has a schedule in it, I mean it's between the `start_time` and `end_time` of a schedule.

---

**EDIT:**

I've got a workaround as of the moment, if you have better answer feel free to post it.

The code below successfully removed all elements that holds the value of like this:

```
[
    0 => 1,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 1
]
```

The code I have:

```
$data = [...];

$filtered = array_filter($data,  fn ($el) => hasSchedule($el));

function hasSchedule($period) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($period); $i++) {
        if(is_array($period[$i])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $sum = array_sum($period);
            if ($sum == 5) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non-loop approach using `array_filter` and a custom function.
To remove all `1`s, we can use the `array_unique` function and check the result if was only one item in the result array and the first element of areay was equal to `1`.

```php
$list = [
    "07:00 AM - 07:05 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 0,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:05 AM - 07:10 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:10 AM - 07:15 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => 1,
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ],
    "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM" => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1,
        2 => [
            "schedule_id"  => 10,
            "time"         => "07:15 AM - 07:20 AM",
            "subject_name" => "Subject Abc",
        ],
        3 => 1,
        4 => 1,
    ]
];

function removeAllOnes($arr)
{
    if (array_filter($arr, 'is_array'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    $_new = array_unique($arr);
    return !(count($_new) == 1 && $_new[0] === 1);
}

$filtered = array_filter($list, 'removeAllOnes');
print_r($filtered);
```

Comment: you're the man! your solution worked for me and it's better than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on the reddit question, but i'm going to post it here too to see if any SO users have any comments on it.

This works because `array_filter` will filter out empty arrays.

```php
$data = array_filter($data, function($period) {
    return array_filter($period, function($item) {
        return $item !== 1;
    });
});
```