# formatting array response from controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a `ScheduleController` that gets the `start_time` and `end_time` from the `schedules` table.

ScheduleController

```
$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')
    ->where('weekday', $request->input('weekday'))
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$collection = collect($schedules)->map(function ($time) {
    return [date("g:i", strtotime($time['start_time'])), date("g:i", strtotime($time['end_time']))];
})->flatten();

$data = $collection->values()->all();

// the $data above produce something like this
['6:30', '7:30'],
['11:30', '12:30']
```

I'm getting the array response from my `ScheduleController`, and in my `blade` file I have a BootStrap `DateTimePicker`, this `DateTimePicker` will use the array response in `disabledTimeIntervals`.

The syntax of [disabledTimeIntervals](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Options/#disabledtimeintervals) looks like the code below, the hour and minutes are hard coded here:

```
// example
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [ moment({ hour: 17, minute: 30 }), moment({ hour: 18, minute: 30 }) ]
],
```

The question is, How can I format the `array` response from my `ScheduleController` to be like this:

```
// FROM
['6:30', '7:30'],
['11:30', '12:30']

// TO
[ moment({ hour: 6, minute: 30 }), moment({ hour: 7, minute: 30 }) ],
[ moment({ hour: 11, minute: 30 }), moment({ hour: 12, minute: 30 }) ]
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried [Mtdt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12966265/mtdt) 's answer, but it's not disabling the hour and minutes if I put multiple arrays, but in the single array it works, See the example below, I manually add it to the code.

```
const stringToDate = (dateString) => {
    const [hours, minutes] = dateString.split(':');
    return moment().hours(hours).minutes(minutes);
}
const formatDates = datesToFormat => datesToFormat.map(dateString => {
    if (Array.isArray(dateString)) {
        return dateString.map(s => stringToDate(s));
    } else {
        return stringToDate(dateString);
    }
})

let customOptions = {
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
        // not working in multiple array 
        formatDates([ ['6:30', '7:30'], ['11:30', '12:30'] ])

        // this one works if single array and not enclosed with []
        formatDates(['6:30', '7:30'])
    ],
}

$('.timepicker').datetimepicker(customOptions)
```

Maybe it's not formatted like below?

```
disabledTimeIntervals: [
    [moment({ hour:6, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:30 })],
    [moment({ hour:11, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:12, minute:30 })]
],
```

This is the result when I `console.log(formatDates([['6:30', '7:30'], ['11:30', '12:30']]))`

[image]

---

**EDIT #2**

I tried doing it the PHP way, but there are still some problems I'm facing.

My problem now is removing the quotes (`"`) in the array result and the extra comma (`,`) at the end. Currently, I have `str_replace('"', "", 'string-here')` but it's not removing the quotes.

My code

```
$user = User::find(1);
$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')
    ->whereBelongsTo($user)
    ->where('weekday', 1)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

$collection = collect($schedules)->map(function ($time) {
    return [date("g:i", strtotime($time['start_time'])), date("g:i", strtotime($time['end_time']))];
});

$data = $collection->values()->all();

// $data produces this result
// [
//   [
//     "6:45",
//     "7:45",
//   ],
//   [
//     "10:30",
//     "11:30",
//   ],
// ]

$carrier = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $a) {
    $detail1 = preg_split('/:/i', $a[0]);
    $detail2 = preg_split('/:/i', $a[1]);

    array_push($carrier, array(str_replace('"', "", 'moment({ hour:'.$detail1[0].', minute:'.$detail1[1].' }), moment({ hour:'.$detail2[0].', minute:'.$detail2[1].' })')));
}

return $carrier;
```

```
// currently this is what I got as the result when I return $carrier
[
  [
    "moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })",
  ],
  [
    "moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })",
  ],
]

// and I want to remove the quotes " and the extra comma , at the end of the string
// so this is the final form
[
  [
    moment({ hour:6, minute:45 }), moment({ hour:7, minute:45 })
  ],
  [
    moment({ hour:10, minute:30 }), moment({ hour:11, minute:30 })
  ],
]
```

Comment: Rather make it `moment`ed on the frontend?

Comment: @nice_dev sorry, I didn't get what you mean, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @nice_dev I mean, if we can `moment`ed it on frontend? yes

Comment: So you can add the moment call in your frontend in the ajax response instead of returning a ready made string from the controller.

Comment: I mean as of now, I don't know how can I separate for example `['6:30']` to `moment({ hour: 6, minute: 30 })`

Answer (score 1):

To have a moment object as you desire:

```
moment().hours(6).minutes(30).seconds(0)
```

A complete script:

```
const datesToFormat = ['6:30', '7:30'];
const formattedDates = datesToFormat.map(dateString => {
 const [hours, minutes] = dateString.split(':');
 return moment().hours(hours).minutes(minutes).seconds(0)
})
```

Read the docs:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

---

EDIT
for multilevel array

```
const stringToDate = (dateString) => {
  const [hours, minutes] = dateString.split(':');
  return moment().hours(hours).minutes(minutes).seconds(0);
}
const formatDates = datesToFormat => datesToFormat.map(dateString => {
 if (Array.isArray(dateString)) {
   return dateString.map(s => stringToDate(s));
 } else {
   return stringToDate(dateString);
 }
})
formatDates(["6:30", "7:30"])
formatDates([["6:30", "7:30"], ["8:30", "9:30"]])
```

Comment: I'll try this one, thank you for providing an answer @Mtdt

Comment: Result of testing:

I tried and it's working fine for a single array, there's a problem when I make it`['6:30', '7:30'], ['11:30', '12:30']` just like in the question. `Invalid destructuring assignment target`

Comment: add a condition, the split() works on string, not array, if you have multilevel array adapt it to your needs, with recursion or however you prefer.

Comment: as a beginner in javascript I'm sorry I can't reach what you mean. I don't know what term to search right now.

Comment: added a solution for a response withouth recursion and only for array with maximum 2 level

Comment: I try to run the updated answer and I `console.log(formatDates)` but gives me this `datesToFormat => datesToFormat.map(dateString => {
                if (Array.isArray(dateString)) {
                    return dateString.map(s => stringToDate(s));
                } else {`

EDIT: sorry I get it now, I need to place `formatDates([["6:30", "7:30"], ["8:30", "9:30"]])` inside `disabledTimeIntervals: []` right?

Comment: do I need a loop for multiple arrays? e,g, `['6:30', '7:30'], ['11:30', '12:30']` seems like a problem if I got that, only the first one is formatted.

Comment: To test it you can use the javascript console (ctrl+shif+i or f12) copy all code an paste it on moment.js page (it has loaded moment.js library). The method map() is a loop, I don't know exactly what you need to do, the example I posted already loop on and array. Try to break it a little bit and rewrite to fit your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure if `formatDates([["6:30", "7:30"], ["8:30", "9:30"]])` is producing this `[ moment({ hour: 6, minute: 30 }), moment({ hour: 7, minute: 30 }) ], [ moment({ hour: 11, minute: 30 }), moment({ hour: 12, minute: 30 }) ]`

Comment: I updated my question to provide the testing result and add an attachment.